# How to call contract's method from crate

Tags: rust, nearprotocol, indexer

I need to call the contract's method from my Indexer. Now I use `tokio::process` and near-cli written on NodeJs. It looks soundless, and I would like to do that from Rust.

Answer (score 1):

### Recommended way

[NEAR JSON-RPC Client RS](https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs) is the recommended way to interact with NEAR Protocol from within the Rust code.

Example from the README

```rust
use near_jsonrpc_client::{methods, JsonRpcClient};
use near_jsonrpc_primitives::types::transactions::TransactionInfo;

let mainnet_client = JsonRpcClient::connect("https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org");

let tx_status_request = methods::tx::RpcTransactionStatusRequest {
    transaction_info: TransactionInfo::TransactionId {
        hash: "9FtHUFBQsZ2MG77K3x3MJ9wjX3UT8zE1TczCrhZEcG8U".parse()?,
        account_id: "miraclx.near".parse()?,
    },
};

// call a method on the server via the connected client
let tx_status = mainnet_client.call(tx_status_request).await?;

println!("{:?}", tx_status);
```

In the [examples folder](https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs/tree/master/examples) of the repo, you will find different use cases, and hopefully, you'll find yours there as well.

`near-jsonrpc-client-rs` is the best option.

### Alternative way

**NB!** This way is using non-documented APIs. It is not recommended way, because using these assumes you will dig into the code and find out how to use it by yourself.

If you're using the [NEAR Indexer Framework](https://near-indexers.io/docs/projects/near-indexer-framework) you're literally running a `nearcore` node which includes:

- JSON RPC server
- `ClientActor` and `ViewClient`

Based on the kind of call you need to perform to your contract: change method or view method, you can use `ClientActor` or `ViewClient`.

### ViewClient example

Code is for understanding the concept, not a working example.

```rust
let indexer = near_indexer::Indexer::new(indexer_config);

let view_client = indexer.client_actors().0;

let block_response = view_client
        .send(query)
        .await
        .context("Failed to deliver response")?
        .context("Invalid request")?;
```

You can find the usage in [NEAR Indexer for Explorer starting from here](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer/blob/b31d7ec3c1cd6571c685644b815aec552631c391/src/aggregated/circulating_supply/mod.rs#L233-L247)

### ClientActor example

`ClientActor` is used to send a transaction. I guess here's [a good starting point](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/chain/jsonrpc/src/lib.rs#L590-L602) to look for `ClientActor` example.

```rust
async fn send_tx_async(
    &self,
    request_data: near_jsonrpc_primitives::types::transactions::RpcBroadcastTransactionRequest,
) -> CryptoHash {
    let tx = request_data.signed_transaction;
    let hash = tx.get_hash().clone();
    self.client_addr.do_send(NetworkClientMessages::Transaction {
        transaction: tx,
        is_forwarded: false,
        check_only: false, // if we set true here it will not actually send the transaction
    });
    hash
}
```

Comment: Here is the direct link to the example that shows how to make a view call: https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs/blob/93cfaecce2b61bc84435751ab93f5849941ebe69/examples/contract_view_method.rs